# Microsoft Teams - Android version - Deeplink not working

Tags: android, microsoft-teams

I have a Microsoft Teams application developed as a Personal App.
This app is having few different personal tabs in that.

The app works fine in the Desktop, web and iOS devices.

But in Android device , it has issues with tab navigation
When I am trying to open one of the tab. It always redirect to the first tab.

For example, I have several tabs like Overview, Campaign, Feedback, Thanks etc.

In Latest version of MS Teams, When I click on the Thanks Tab it always redirect me to Overview tab.

That same thing is working in iOS and older version of MS Teams.

This behavior is also reported in GitHub Repo as well.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/4028

Comment: We can't figure it out until you post the code. We cannot see what is wrong on your code

Comment: I think there is nothing in the code. As it works in the older version of MS Teams.

Comment: Might be. If it works on older versions, it should work on newest version as well. Without code we cant help you. Sorry

Comment: What should I show you as a code? That is an OOTB tab. which is not changing

Comment: Just view pager code. Is it ViewPager or ViewPager2

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Please refer this question, I am facing same issue 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/4028

Comment: They are saying that it's a bug and will be fixed soon. There is nothing wrong with code. Wait and see if the bug is solved. There was no need of asking question. We cant fix the bug, can we? Only the microsoft devs can fix it

Comment: thanks. if it is return there , That means it is confirmed from their side correct?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: You have to wait

Comment: till then enjoy your app

Comment: This issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed and will be available generally next month.
GitHub issue link for your reference:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/4136